# Assign IP address in a LAN

Tags: java, networking

I need to assign IP addresses to computers in a LAN through programming (preferably java).

The Client will have a form with few buttons each of which have default IP address.
when a user clicks on any one of the button, the server(on windows) needs to assign a new IP address from a range of IP addresses for each button.

This is only for a demo purpose for a college project.

I would greatly appreciate for ant posts, blog.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you do this depends on the operating system you have.  I assume you are root or administrator and you program is running on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two threads related to your question:

[Change Computer IP address using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231227/change-computer-ip-address-using-java)
[how to change local machine/ethernet ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376215/how-to-change-local-machine-ethernet-ip-address)

However, if you want to assign IP address for other computer in a LAN, then you probably need to read about DHCP. You will need to build the communication with a particular host first without knowing their address.